# how to erase element from vector<char>?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector with char type;

```
vector<char> a_chars;
```

and it contains 6 characters but 3 of them are duplicate.
How can I delete the duplicate char? Here is my current code and it doesnt compile:

```
for(int i = 0; i < a_chars.size(); i++)
    {
        char current = a_chars.at(i);
        for(int j = i+1; j < a_chars.size(); j++)
        {
            if (current == a_chars.at(j))
            {
                a_chars.erase[j];
            }
        }
    }
```

here is the compile error: "C:invalid types '[int]' for array subscript|"

EDIT:
Also I have tried with `a_chars.erase(j)` and `a_chars.erase(a_chars.at(j)` and still had compile error.

Comment: the error is at this line "a_chars.erase[j];"

Comment: You do know that [`std::vector::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) is a member *function*?

Comment: You also need to think about what happens when you erase an element, and how your indexing will be affected.

Comment: Just like you'd erase an element from a vector of anything else.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg I have tried with a_chars.erase(j); and a_chars.erase(a_chars.at(j)); none of them seems to worked. Can you be a little bit more precise?

Comment: If you follow the link to the reference, you will see that the [`erase` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) takes an *iterator* argument. You *have* used iterator before, have you not? The reference also contain a simple example you could read.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I just found it out by myself, I wish someone could tell me that yesterday, I am still new with iterators and vectors and I was a  bit confused. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some attempts I found out by my self. 
It is not working with `a_chars.erase[j];` nor `a_chars.erase(j);` neither `a_chars.erase(a_chars.at(j));`. All I had to do is make an iterator and make it same as 'j'.

```
                vector<char>::iterator itr = a_chars.begin();
                itr+=j;
                a_chars.erase(itr);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std::unique` with combination of `vector::erase` method (known as [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom)). The vector has to be, however, sorted.

```
vector<char> a_chars;
std::sort(a_chars.begin(), a_chars.end());
a_chars.erase(std::unique(a_chars.begin(), a_chars.end()), a_chars.end());
```

If you don't want to sort your `vector`. You can use following snippet to remove duplicites.

```
void remove_duplicities(std::vector<char>& vec)
{
    for (auto iter = vec.begin(); iter != vec.end(); ++iter)
    {
        for (auto jter = std::next(iter); jter != vec.end(); ++jter)
        {
            if (*iter == *jter)
                jter = std::prev(vec.erase(jter));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works only if he is not interested about the primary order.

Comment: @Esus Then use std::stable_sort... I think his problems aren't at this point of engineering yet, but rather what member functions are.

Comment: @dascandy since OP's `vector` contains `char`s, the order does not matter.

Comment: your code worked fine, but why do I have compile error at my code? I also forgot to mention that I tried also with "a_chars.erase(j)" and "a_chars.erase(a_chars.at(j))" and none of them worked.

Comment: because `vector::erase` does not have overload, which takes value as argument.